# LESS: How to @import files from the parent folder

Tags: import, less, prepros

I have a question regarding @import .LESS files. For compilation into CSS I use Prepros (http://prepros.io/).

My current project's structure is:

```
- all_projects/
---- assets/
------ partials/
-------- partial1.less
-------- partial2.less
------ mixins.less
---- project/
------ project_styles.less
------ variables.less
```

I need to include mixins.less and all partilas from the assets/partials/ folder into project_styles.less. I tried to @import them in an obviuos way "../assets..." but it didn't work. Here's a code example:

**project_styles.less**

```
@import '../assets/mixins.less';
@import 'variables.less';
@import '../assets/partials/partial1.less';
@import '../assets/partials/partial2.less';
```

I tried several solutions found at Stackowerflow etc (http://goo.gl/yvtpFb) but none on them worked.

Can you please point me into right direction how to achieve this?
Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

The way you described this is the way it should work.

You could try this with grunt of gulp and the gulp/grunt-less package. I think the application you use has some issues. If gulp/grunt is not an option you could try to adjust the folder structure. Try:

```
- all_projects/
-- project/
---- partials/
------ partial1.less
------ partial2.less
------ mixins.less
------ variables.less
---- project_styles.less
```

This way you keep all the partials together mixins and variables are soft of partials also.

Imports then should be like this:

```
@import '../project/partials/partial1.less';
@import '../project/partials/partial2.less';
@import '../project/partials/mixins.less';
@import '../project/partials/variables.less';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, it's useless to unite all projects in the same folder because in this case I'll get a messy structure. That's why I need each project (done for separate customer) in its separate folder. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: I was suggesting a solution that maybe would solve your issue. I think your problem lies within the application you work with not the way how the Less syntax should work

Comment: Yes, I've asked the app's author why this happened. But unfortunately I didn't receive any answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how **prepros.io** works but LESS has `http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-options` to set compiling process and of these is the following:

```
relativeUrls: false
```

According to docs:

> Optionally adjust URLs to be relative. When false, URLs are already
>   relative to the entry less file.

I suggest you to look into this direction.

Comment: Thank you for the tip :) But these settings work for Less.js only. If I could use something like "config.rb" file as for Sass... Unfortunately, I didn't find such information yet.